# Git commit not possible. There are no staged files

Tags: eclipse, git, commit, egit, eclipse-mars

I am using EGits with Eclipse and running into some issues.

I have one change from head; I have made one new class.

When I right click on this class and click "push", the following dialog shows and I cannot get past it :

[image: Dialog box with "Committing is not posssible. There are no staged files".]

Anyway, I need to push this file because I can't commit in real life, and now I cannot commit in Eclipse either and it's taking it's toll mentally.

Thanks.

PS I have googled this extensively looking for an easy fix (like a "stage" button) and found nothing.

Comment: You need to find the Git staging view and then add the modified file and new file to the index.  It appears that eGit is not doing this for you automatically.  Or, as a backup, you can just `git add` these files from the Git Bash.

Comment: Right click on that file and select `Add to Index`

Comment: *"I can't commit in real life"* You definitely need more commitment then.

Comment: "Git staging view and then add the modified file and new file to the index" - this helped me

Answer (score 20, accepted):

using EGit:
Right click it and navigate to Team => Add.

after then Push the code

Before pushing the file add that new file on git using terminal

git add  after then

git push origin branch

Answer (score 0):

OR you need to `add to Index` first before committing it.